# Need to incorporate event calendar in ASP.NET website?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to incoporate event calander in my website (ASP.NET).

I go through from the below event calender.

**wdCalendar** 
http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/sample.php

Can someone suggest some event calander which can handle events on day, week and month basis?

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/download/ then you will have problem with recurring events it is upto you how you design your database & what type of events you want to handle. I started to work with it few days back. I managed to pull it off but it is not very flexible when it comes to recurring. I managed to pull it off but my version still supports weekly recurring it cant handle monthly recurring. I suggest if you have time then work on wdCalendar calender  .. Example of ASP.Net version of this can be found on this blog http://wdcalendar.blogspot.com/. I am my self looking for something very similar.

If you are looking for paid version then 
They provide ASP.NET AJAX and ASP.NET MVC controls.

Calendar: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Scheduler: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

OR

http://scheduler-net.com/docs/common_application_with_scheduler.html